# Every n-th element of a list

Tags: python

I want to delete every n-th element of a Python list. When I reach the end of the list, I want to go back to beginning from where I left off and to continue this process until only one element remains.

My Code is :

```
my_list=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
n=3
while len(my_list)>1:
  del my_list[n-1::n]
  print(my_list)
```

But, it didn't work corretly.

> Extra Explanation : If n=3, I want it to delete 3 and 6 in the first step. For the second step, it must to continue to count from 7 (next element of the last deleted element. Last deleted element was 6. So, it must to start to count from 7). When it count to 3 element starting from 7, it must to delete 1. So on...

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to implement a brute-force solution to the [Josephus problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem) (inspired by the advent of code, perhaps?). It's worth noting that the index of the "surviving" element can be computed directly, without manually deleting elements from the list.

Comment: I don't know Josephus problem. My problem is just as I explained above.

Comment: If the list is `[4,7]` and `n=3`, how do you know which one to delete?  Or generally if `len(thelist) < n` - how do you choose?

Comment: It's like going in a circle. If you start from 4 to count while n=3, it is like this : 4,7,4. That is it must to delete 4.

Comment: That will result in `[4,7]` **again** and it will never stop.

Comment: No, 4 is deleted from the list. Just [7] remained.

Comment: So essentially if `n-len(thelist) == 1` the delete the first item?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution that i came up with that worked for me.

```
nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
pos=3-1                         #since list starts from '0'
index = 0
len_list = (len(nums)) 
while len_list > 1: 

    index = (pos + index) % len_list 
    print(nums.pop(index)) # removes and prints the required element 
    len_list -= 1
print(nums[0])             #print the last remaining number in the list
```

**Output:7**

Answer (score 2):

This is a circular array problem where you need to delete every nth element till you reached the last element. Below is the solution for it

```
my_list=[1, 2, 3, 4 ,5, 6, 7, 8]

def func(lis,n):
    if n>len(lis):
        return -1
    while len(lis)!=1:
        del lis[::n]
    return lis

print(func(my_list, 3))

# output [8]
```

Comment: You right that it is a circular array problem. But, your solution doesn't work as I want. For example if n=3, I want it to delete 3 and 6 in the first step. For the second step, it must to continue to count from 7  (next element of the last deleted element. Last deleted element was 6. So, it must to start to count from 7). When it count to 3 element starting from 7, it must to delete 1.

Answer (score 1):

I think this logic is correct.

```
def f(a,n):
    if len(a) == 1:
        return a[0]
    elif n - len(a) == 1:
        return a[-1]
    if len(a) < n:
        a.extend(a[:n-len(a)])
    q,r = divmod(len(a),n)
    if r == 0:
        first,second = a,[]
    else:
        first,second = a[:-r],a[-r:]
    del first[n-1::n]
    second.extend(first)
    return f(second,n)
```

---